# Extract specific length numbers from string and create new string with those numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a text field that I need to extract certain numbers from.  The number will always be 7 digits long but the location within the string is not known and how many are in the string is also not known.

A sample string is "SF WO  1564892  DUE 5/19 FIN WO  1638964  DUE 5/27".  I want to be able to extract 1564892 and 1638964 and have it generate a new string like "1564892;1638964" and continue to add ";number" if there are more in the string.  I use the new string to find and return the largest of these numbers.

I found this and it kind of works but it will also return "1234567" from the string "123456789" which is undesired.

```
Public Function ExtractDigits(Alphanumeric As String, DigitLength As Long)
Dim StringLenght As Long
Dim CurrentCharacter As String
Dim NewString As String
Dim NumberCounter As Long
Dim TempString As String


StringLenght = Len(Alphanumeric)
For r = 1 To StringLenght
    CurrentCharacter = Mid(Alphanumeric, r, 1)
    If IsNumeric(CurrentCharacter) Then
        NumberCounter = NumberCounter + 1
        TempString = TempString & CurrentCharacter
        If NumberCounter = DigitLength Then
            If NewString = "" Then
                NewString = TempString
            Else
            NewString = NewString & ";" & TempString
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(CurrentCharacter) Then
        NumberCounter = 0
        TempString = ""
    End If
Next

ExtractDigits = NewString

End Function
```

I would prefer the solution be in VBA and not a function but I am open to anything.

Comment: You could add an additional condition to the `If NumberCounter = DigitLength Then` line of code that checks if the next character is a space or not, for example: `If NumberCounter = DigitLength And Mid(Alphanumeric, r + 1, 1) = " " Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can your problem be solved by adding an additional If-statement that tests whether the character after the 7th number is a number as well and ignore the number if that is the case?

```
Public Function ExtractDigits(Alphanumeric As String, DigitLength As Long)
Dim StringLenght As Long
Dim CurrentCharacter As String
Dim NewString As String
Dim NumberCounter As Long
Dim TempString As String
Dim r As Integer


StringLenght = Len(Alphanumeric)
For r = 1 To StringLenght
    CurrentCharacter = Mid(Alphanumeric, r, 1)
    If IsNumeric(CurrentCharacter) Then
        NumberCounter = NumberCounter + 1
        TempString = TempString & CurrentCharacter
        If NumberCounter = DigitLength Then
            If (Not IsNumeric(Mid(Alphanumeric, r + 1, 1))) Then
                If NewString = "" Then
                    NewString = TempString
                Else
                NewString = NewString & ";" & TempString
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If Not IsNumeric(CurrentCharacter) Then
        NumberCounter = 0
        TempString = ""
    End If
Next

ExtractDigits = NewString

End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want can be achieved using `RegEx` but since I am stepping out so here is a very **simple alternative** :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim s As String
    Dim MyAr As Variant
    Dim i as Long

    s = "Thisis a Sample1234567-Blah12341234\1384156 Blah Blah 1375188 and more Blah 20 Section 1"

    For i = Len(s) To 1 Step -1
        Select Case Asc(Mid(s, i, 1))
        Case 48 To 57
        Case Else
            s = Replace(s, Mid(s, i, 1), "a")
        End Select
    Next i

    Do While InStr(1, s, "aa")
        s = Replace(s, "aa", "a")
    Loop

    MyAr = Split(s, "a")

    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        If Len(Trim(MyAr(i))) = 7 Then Debug.Print MyAr(i)
    Next i
    '
    ' This will Give you 1234567, 1384156 and 1375188
    '
End Sub
```

**Edit**

**Logic**

1. Replace anything in that string which is not a number with any alphabet
2. Replace double instancs of that alphabet till only one remains
3. Split on that alphabet
4. Loop and check for the length.
5. I have displayed those numbers. You can join them

Answer (score 2):

I faced such thing in the past, and hope this approach will help.

```
Function Extract7Digits(s As String) As String

Dim i As Long 
Dim SevenDigits As String 
Dim s2 As String

s2 = Replace(s, " ", "|") 
i = 1 
While i < Len(s2) - 7
    If IsNumeric(Mid(s2, i, 7)) Then
        SevenDigits = SevenDigits & Mid(s2, i, 7) & ";"
        i=i+6
    End If
    i = i + 1 
Wend
    Extract7Digits = SevenDigits 
End Function
```

Best.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Regex which is much easier than looping over the whole string.

The regex being used is `\b\d{7}\b` which means 7 digits delimited by word boundary.

```
Public Function ExtractDigits(Alphanumeric As String, DigitLength As Long) As String
    Dim regEx As Object, matches As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim output As String

    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .pattern = "\b\d{" & DigitLength & "}\b"
    End With

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(Alphanumeric)
    For i = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        output = output & matches(i) & ";"
    Next
    If Len(output) > 0 Then output = Left(output, Len(output) - 1)
    ExtractDigits = output
End Function
```